# Codesign fails during xcodebuild archive in Bamboo only

Tags: ios, xcode8, bamboo

I have a script that builds and archives an iOS App using xcodebuild. Running it manually on the CI server works perfectly, but it always fails if run as a task in Bamboo:

```
/Users/bamboo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fznnexbqdbnwoebohwwvajvtmcdf/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LIVE/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff

Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

the archive command looks like this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "${workspace}" -scheme "${scheme}" -archivePath "${archive_path}" clean archive
```

I did try:

- using `security unlock-keychain` before the `xcodebuild` command
- chaining `security unlock-keychain` and `xcodebuild` commands with `&&`
- manually unlocking keychain
- moving the signing certificate and key to System keychain
- setting `Allow all applications to access this item` in keychain
- searching SO and everything else (even asking the janitor :) )

If this is of any help, the project uses manual signing, the profile and certificate are specified in build settings because those change quite often, nevertheless the logs show that the right signing identity is picked up.

Any suggestions of what could be wrong are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and paste this two:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
xattr -rc .
```